# Why this generic interface implementation doesn't complile?

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors

Why this generic interface implementation doesn't complile?

```
//The type Client<T> must implement the inherited abstract method IClient.compareTo(IClient)
class Client<T> implements IClient {

    //The method compareTo(IClient<T>) of type Client<T> must override or implement a supertype method
    //The Eclipse quick fix creates exactly the same supertype method which is defined in the interface.
    @Override
    public int compareTo( IClient<T> o ) {  
        return this.getClass().getName().compareTo( o.getClass().getName() );
    }
}

interface IClient<T> extends Comparable<IClient<T>> {

    @Override
    int compareTo( IClient<T> o );

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh, I found out that there is a name clash: 
*The method compareTo(IClient) of type Client has the same erasure as compareTo(IClient) of type IClient but does not override it.*

IClient is a raw type. References to generic type IClient should be parameterized

`class Client<T> implements IClient<T>` will fix it.

Comment: @The Elite Gentleman: oliholz posted his answer before ysdx did.

Answer (score 3):

```
 class Client<T> implements IClient<T> {
```

Comment: yes, found it, it was so simple. sometimes it helps to write down the question.